# Pagination in DynamoDB using Node.js?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, pagination, amazon-dynamodb

I've had a read through [AWS's docs around pagination](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.Pagination.html):

As their docs specify:

> In a response, DynamoDB returns all the matching results within the scope of the Limit value. For example, if you issue a Query or a Scan request with a Limit value of 6 and without a filter expression, DynamoDB returns the first six items in the table that match the specified key conditions in the request (or just the first six items in the case of a Scan with no filter)

Which means that given I have a table called `Questions` with an attribute called `difficulty`(that can take any numeric value ranging from `0` to `2`) I might end up with the following conundrum:

- A client makes a request, think `GET /questions?difficulty=0&limit=3`
- I forward that `3` to the DynamoDB query, which might return `0` items as the first 3 in the collection might not be of `difficulty == 0`
- I then have to perform a new query to fetch more `questions` that match that criteria without knowing I might return duplicates

How can I then paginate based on a query correctly? Something where I'll get as many results as I asked for whilst having the correct offset

Comment: Why wouldn't you have a `LastEvaluatedKey`? Have your client handle receiving a `LastEvaluatedKey` and sending it in subsequent requests via the query string.

Comment: I do have a `LastEvaluatedKey` let me amend that - What I wanted to express is that my offset doesn't correspond to results...but to documents scanned. if that makes sense?

Answer (score 32):

Using async/await.

```
const getAllData = async (params) => { 

    console.log("Querying Table");
    let data = await docClient.query(params).promise();

    if(data['Items'].length > 0) {
        allData = [...allData, ...data['Items']];
    }

    if (data.LastEvaluatedKey) {
        params.ExclusiveStartKey = data.LastEvaluatedKey;
        return await getAllData(params);

    } else {
        return data;
    }
}
```

I am using a global variable **allData** to collect all the data.

Calling this function is enclosed within a try-catch

```
try {

        await getAllData(params);
        console.log("Processing Completed");

        // console.log(allData);

    } catch(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
```

I am using this from within a **Lambda** and it works fine.

The article [here](https://blog.scottlogic.com/2017/09/14/asynchronous-recursion.html) really helped and guided me. Thanks.

Comment: Couple of downsides to this solution: 1) it's unnecessarily recursive, which is problematic at some level and 2) it uses global variables.

Answer (score 20):

Here is an example of how to iterate over a paginated result set from 
a DynamoDB `scan` (can be easily adapted for `query` as well) in Node.js.

You could save the `LastEvaluatedKey` state serverside and pass an identifier back to your client, which it would send with its next request and your server would pass that value as `ExclusiveStartKey` in the next request to DynamoDB.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.logger = console;

const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB({ apiVersion: '2012-08-10' });

let val = 'some value';

let params = {
  TableName: "MyTable",
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ':val': {
      S: val,
    },
  },
  Limit: 1000,
  FilterExpression: 'MyAttribute = :val',
  // ExclusiveStartKey: thisUsersScans[someRequestParamScanID]
};

dynamodb.scan(scanParams, function scanUntilDone(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err, err.stack);
  } else {
    // do something with data

    if (data.LastEvaluatedKey) {
      params.ExclusiveStartKey = data.LastEvaluatedKey;

      dynamodb.scan(params, scanUntilDone);
    } else {
      // all results scanned. done!
      someCallback();
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: It would be great to see this example using async/await since all aws js sdk client functions support it.

Comment: I have added an answer with the async/await version @JohnSmith

Answer (score 17):

Avoid using recursion to prevent call stack overflow. An iterative solution extending @Roshan Khandelwal's approach:

```
const getAllData = async (params) => {
  const _getAllData = async (params, startKey) => {
    if (startKey) {
      params.ExclusiveStartKey = startKey
    }
    return this.documentClient.query(params).promise()
  }
  let lastEvaluatedKey = null
  let rows = []
  do {
    const result = await _getAllData(params, lastEvaluatedKey)
    rows = rows.concat(result.Items)
    lastEvaluatedKey = result.LastEvaluatedKey
  } while (lastEvaluatedKey)
  return rows
}
```

Answer (score 11):

I hope you figured out. So just in case others might find it useful. AWS has QueryPaginator/ScanPaginator as simple as below:

```
const paginator = new QueryPaginator(dynamoDb, queryInput);

for await (const page of paginator) {
    // do something with the first page of results
    break
}
```

See more details at https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-data-mapper-js/tree/master/packages/dynamodb-query-iterator

2022-05-19:
For AWS SDK v3 see how to use `paginateXXXX` at this blog post https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/pagination-using-async-iterators-in-modular-aws-sdk-for-javascript/

Comment: Just created an article on how-to paginate using paginateScan and paginateQuery from AWS SDK here: https://medium.com/p/844b6d1ffc83

Answer (score 5):

Query and Scan operations return `LastEvaluatedKey` in their responses. Absent concurrent insertions, you will not miss items nor will you encounter items multiple times, as long as you iterate calls to Query/Scan and set ExclusiveStartKey to the LastEvaluatedKey of the previous call.

Comment: Hi @Alexander, i have a use case. Can you tell me, like for example user directly lands to `https://www.example.com/food?page=4&pagesize=20`, how can we fetch the data from the middle of the range like, i don't have `LastEvaluatedKey` in this case?

Comment: @ArpitAgrawal have you solved this issue? I have similar use case

Comment: Hi @SubanDhyako , no there is no alternative i found for the same, so we handled it on our end my manually calculating the items if LastKey is not specified, otherwise we use the last key.

Answer (score 3):

For create pagination in dynamodb scan like

```
var params = {  
        "TableName"                 : "abcd",
        "FilterExpression"          : "#someexperssion=:someexperssion",
        "ExpressionAttributeNames"  : {"#someexperssion":"someexperssion"},
        "ExpressionAttributeValues" : {":someexperssion" : "value"},
        "Limit"                     : 20,
        "ExclusiveStartKey"         : {"id": "9ee10f6e-ce6d-4820-9fcd-cabb0d93e8da"}
    };
DB.scan(params).promise();
```

where ExclusiveStartKey is LastEvaluatedKey return by this query last execution time

Answer (score 3):

Using async/await, returning the data in await.
Elaboration on @Roshan Khandelwal's answer.

```
const getAllData = async (params, allData = []) => {
  const data = await dynamodbDocClient.scan(params).promise()

  if (data['Items'].length > 0) {
    allData = [...allData, ...data['Items']]
  }

  if (data.LastEvaluatedKey) {
    params.ExclusiveStartKey = data.LastEvaluatedKey
    return await getAllData(params, allData)
  } else {
    return allData
  }
}
```

Call inside a try/catch:

```
try {
        const data = await getAllData(params);
        console.log("my data: ", data);
    } catch(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
```

Comment: Scan is really slow consider an example with Query

Answer (score 0):

you can do a index secundary by difficulty and at query set KeyConditionExpression where difficulty  = 0. Like this

```
var params = {
    TableName: questions,
    IndexName: 'difficulty-index',
    KeyConditionExpression: 'difficulty = :difficulty ',
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {':difficulty':0}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve this using recrusion instead of a global variable, like:

```js
const getAllData = async (params, allData = []) => {
    let data = await db.scan(params).promise();
    return (data.LastEvaluatedKey) ?
      getAllData({...params, ExclusiveStartKey: data.LastEvaluatedKey}, [...allData, ...data['Items']]) :
      [...allData, ...data['Items']];
};
```

Then you can simply call it like:

```js
 let test = await getAllData({ "TableName": "test-table"}); // feel free to add try/catch
```

Answer (score 0):

Using DynamoDB pagination with async generators:

```
let items = []
let params = {
    TableName: 'mytable',
    Limit: 1000,
    KeyConditionExpression: 'mykey = :key',
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ':key': { S: 'myvalue' },
    },
}

async function* fetchData({
    params
  }) {
    let data
    do {
      data = await dynamodb.query(params).promise()
      yield data.Items
      params.ExclusiveStartKey = data.LastEvaluatedKey
    } while (typeof data.LastEvaluatedKey != 'undefined')
  }

for await (const data of fetchData(params)) {
    items = [...items, ...data]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

example in typescript using recursion

```
import { QueryCommandInput } from "@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb/dist-types/commands/QueryCommand";
import { DynamoDBClient, QueryCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb";

export const getAllDataDynamodb = async (params: QueryCommandInput) => {
    const dynamodbClient = new DynamoDBClient({ region: process.env.AWS_REGION });
    const command = new QueryCommand(params);
    let data: any[] = [];
    const results = await dynamodbClient.send(command);
    if (results.Items.length) {
        data = results.Items;
    }
    if (results.LastEvaluatedKey) {
        console.log("Scanning for more...", results);
        params.ExclusiveStartKey = results.LastEvaluatedKey;
        data = [...data, ...(await getAllDataDynamodb(params))];
    }
    return data;
}
```

Comment: You haven't described your approach, also this is using AWS V3 SDK, you should mention that in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete example of how to use the `paginateQuery` utility from @aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb.

```js
import {
  DynamoDBClient,
  QueryCommandInput,
  QueryCommandOutput,
  paginateQuery,
} from "@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb";

const dbClient = new DynamoDBClient({ region: "us-east-1" });

const items: QueryCommandOutput[] = [];

const query: QueryCommandInput = {
  TableName: VIDEOS_TABLE_NAME,
  IndexName: "GSI1",
  KeyConditionExpression: "GSI1PK = :videoId",
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ":videoId": { S: "VIDEO#123" },
  },
};

const pager = paginateQuery({ client: dbClient }, query);

for await (const item of pager) {
  items.push(item);
}

// all the output from query
console.log(items);
```

Comment: is this the prescribed way to do this according to AWS? seems @user2061811 has not accepted an answer

Comment: Yes @babycakes. AWS has officially published the utility and have told to use it for pagination.